# Using JMeter + Maven with https protocol

Tags: maven-2, ssl-certificate, jmeter

I have been trying hard to make https request work with JMeter+Maven.
Whole Scenarios is - Lauch app URL > login to app (this is https) > on Home page (this is http)

I recorded these tests using HTTP Proxy of JMeter. And then as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299529/jmeter-successfull-https-recording) changed the "HTTP request protocol" of sampler to "https"

Now when I execute the test form Maven I encounter following exception JMeter log -

```
2010/09/08 16:25:38 ERROR - jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager: Exception occurred java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager.getKeyStore(SSLManager.java:132)
at org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager.getContext(JsseSSLManager.java:141)
at org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager.<init>(JsseSSLManager.java:88)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager.getInstance(SSLManager.java:231)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler.setupConnection(HTTPSampler.java:148)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler.sample(HTTPSampler.java:404)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:658)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:647)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:247)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

 2010/09/08 16:25:38 INFO  - jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager: JsseSSLManager installed 
 2010/09/08 16:25:38 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler: You may have forgotten to set the ssl.provider property in jmeter.properties java.lang.IllegalStateException: SSLContextImpl is not initialized
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl.engineGetSocketFactory(SSLContextImpl.java:145)
at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getSocketFactory(SSLContext.java:260)
at com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContextSpiWrapper.engineGetSocketFactory(SSLSecurity.java:365)
at com.sun.net.ssl.SSLContext.getSocketFactory(SSLContext.java:168)
at org.apache.jmeter.util.JsseSSLManager.setContext(JsseSSLManager.java:101)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler.setupConnection(HTTPSampler.java:160)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler.sample(HTTPSampler.java:404)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:658)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:647)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:247)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

One more thing when I execute these tests from JMeter itself then I don't encounter any exception. But invocation of test from with in Maven causes this problem

Have u guys ever been able to execute test successfully on https using JMeter+Maven

Thanks in advance
Tarun K

Comment: it looks like it is a certificate issue "at org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager.getKeyStore(SSLManager.java:132)"  Could it be that Maven isn't accessing the keystore correctly?

Comment: Hmmm.. well I would say that I had to have Maven-Jmeter plugin installed manually from here - https://sass4j.dev.java.net/files/documents/8536/91313/jmeter-plugin-bundle-1.0.zip as there is no public repo currently keeping this plugin. 
I am new to Maven-Jmeter and how do I get to know if Maven is not accessing keystore correctly?

~ T

Comment: I had a look at xml file which is generated after tests and most of its lines say - 
"<httpSample t="78" lt="0" ts="1283963419756" s="false" lb="/" rc="Non HTTP response code" rm="Non HTTP response message" tn="Thread Group 1-1" dt="text"/>"

The very first sample is https in the request...
I find it more surprising because I don't encounter any exception when I execute test from JMeter it self!

Comment: Thoughts: 1. Have you gotten strict HTTP requests to work in Maven?  2. Is Maven pointed to the same jre as Jmeter? the jre\lib\security is where the cacert file lives and helps with security.

Comment: Yup http works perfect with Maven. I stumbled upon this - http://www.jajakarta.org/jmeter/1.5.1/en/running.html which speaks of using JSSE for JMeter. I am using java 1.6 and get to see "jsse.jar" in jre/lib folder. I have also set JMeter properties - "ssl.provider=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider" but I still come across this problem. I am afraid that probably my JMeter properties file is not being considered......

Comment: Came across execution of JMeter tests from ant - http://www.programmerplanet.org/pages/projects/jmeter-ant-task.php 
This set up works well even with https.... Looks like there is some thing missing/outdated with JMeter set up of Maven.... When I use ANT it would directly be referring to JMeter installation but with Maven set up it would be using JMeter plugin and associated dependencies....

Answer (score 0):

JMeter group is suggested me to use updated version of "jmeter.jar" instead of the one available from JMeter Maven plugin.... I am going to mark this question as answered and have filed [another query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691854/how-do-i-build-jmeter-jar) in this regard.

Thanks for ur time Black

~ T

Answer (score 0):

Yes jmeter works with https i am able to get through jemter tests with maven and https, try adding the certificate to cacerts pointed by server.xml using keytool