# How do I build Jmeter.jar

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have trouble using SSL pages with JMeter, which I previously posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667046/using-jmeter-maven-with-https-protocol).

I heard from the JMeter official group that problem might lie in `jmeter.jar`, which is used by the JMeter Maven plug-in, as its version is 2.2 whilst the current version of JMeter is 2.4.

I had a look at my JMeter directory and saw `ApacheJMeter.jar`, but I don't think it is the same as `jmeter.jar`, since `ApacheJMeter.jar` seems to have much fewer classes than `jmeter.jar`.

Where could I get the `jmeter.jar` file from, or how could I build it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fixed in the latest version which is now available from the central maven repository so you no longer need to specify a repository in your POM to use it, all that is required now is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jmeter-tests</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jmeter</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It will pull down the latest JMeter 2.6 artifacts that have been released by Apache and are in the maven central repo as well (So you no longer need to worry about finding JMeter artifacts and/or building them yourself).

Note that the GroupID and ArtifactID have changed.

Project website is http://jmeter.lazerycode.com

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a clean solution to your problem.

The latest `JMeter` version is 2.4 while the `JMeter Maven plugin` uses a **custom** jar called `jmeter-2.2.jar`. This is a user contributed plugin and **the contributor has created this custom jar for use with the Maven plugin**.

Having seen the jar and compared the contents, it looks to be a combination of the contents present in these 2 jars from Apache -  `JMETER_HOME/lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_components.jar` and `JMETER_HOME/lib/ext/ApacheJMeter_core.jar`.

What you could try is to `mvn:deploy` both these jars from JMeter 2.4 into your local repository similar to the `jmeter-2.2.jar` [as done here](http://wiki.apache.org/jakarta-jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin)

If that doesnt work, then make your own `jmeter-2.4.jar` by extracting these 2 completely and creating one single jar out of them.

This still does not ensure the version of JMeterMavenPlugin will work with this new code from 2.4

Alternately, try contacting [one of the plugin authors](http://wiki.apache.org/jakarta-jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin?action=info) to see if they have any advice.

Comment: I am bit confused with this - 
"What you could try is to mvn:deploy both these jars from JMeter 2.4 into your local repository similar to the jmeter-2.2.jar as done here"
Doing so how would I get one jar which is combination of both jars....?

Comment: Between found a couple more jars in - jakarta-jmeter-2.4\lib\ext - ApacheJMeter_http.jar and ApacheJMeter_functions.jar. Though functions are not there in jmeter 2.2 but figured that this should be the reason how my JMeter tests using csv read function works in Jmeter but fails while using Maven JMeter plug-in...