# jmeter encoded data while recording

Tags: jmeter

When I record a script in jmeter, it's recording data in encoded format. Something link below in the body data:

`0D0B0@0>0<0    + @Fzñæ²Ó   º ~~Y7H$ÄÃóüÓF4»ÎF |[óâËYù`

If I tried to click on parameters since it is login data I want to parametrize, after clicking on parameters it says you cannot switch because data cannot be converted.

When I record script for the first time, requests are sent to the web server but when replaying nothing goes to the web server. I want to run with 200 threads on jmeter but facing above issues. Could any one throw some light on this please.

Comment: have tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299529/jmeter-successful-https-recording

Comment: are you recording HTTP or HTTPS? also how the data for the same request looks in browser developer tools?