# SSLHandshakeException when using recording in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

The webpage breaks when using recording in JMeter.

I started the Test script recorder and entered the URL in Firefox browser
(manual proxy config are done correctly in Firefox browser)

The page do not load correctly and gives error

When i see "View Result Tree" in workbench it shows following error various times

> "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca" 
>   java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

I am new to JMeter. while giving instructions please explain it simply so that i can understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must accept the Security rule exception when loading the first page in browser.

Also it is very helpful to install the CA certificate that JMeter generates in the browser, see:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49614949/460802

Comment: I always accept the security rule and add the exception. It dint help. However  i will surely try the suggestion of adding certificate and update here the after results